# Symmetric difference of symmetric difference

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X, Y, Z \neq \emptyset$. The set of elements that belong to exactly two of the sets $X,Y,Z$ was asked in the question and
$(X\cup Y\cup Z) \setminus \left( \left(X\triangle Y\right) \triangle Z\right)$ was given as the answer
I worked this out using Venn diagrams and found this[image: Venn diagram where unshaded portion gives the required value]
Here the unshaded portion gives the required value and we can see that this portion belongs to all 3 sets, which contradicts our assumption.
I have just begun discrete maths, and I have been sitting with this for a long time. Could you please say where I am going wrong?

Comment: "we can see that [the unshaded] portion belongs to all 3 sets".  This is the part I'm not seeing.  The part belonging to all three sets would be the dead center, which is shaded in your right hand sketch.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought that the unshaded portions combined must belong to exactly two sets. Thank you. I should have read the question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the illustration of $X\Delta Y$:

[image]

[image]

This is the illustration of $(X\Delta Y)\Delta Z$:

[image]

[image]

Thus, convince yourself that $X\cup Y\cup Z \setminus ((X\Delta Y)\Delta Z)$ is the set of all elements that belong to exactly two of $X,Y,Z$.

Answer (score 2):

$X \Delta Y \Delta Z$ is the set of all points that are in an odd number (i.e. 1 or 3) of the sets $X,Y,Z$. This is well-known and true for any number of "summands".

So $X \cup Y \cup Z \setminus (X \Delta Y \Delta Z)$ is the set that is in exactly two of them.